# Set control visible from other form

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

I set the button visible property to false of `Form2`. How I will make the button(`Form2`) visible when I click a button(a button that also opens `Form2`) from `Form1`.

I tried this :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 f2 = new Form2();
    f2.Show();
    f2.button1.Visible = true;
    f2.button1.Location = new Point(200, 200);
}
```

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: Already you set visible false in button then how can you click that button?

Comment: button in Form2 is visible false not the one in Form1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a method in Form2

```
public void setButton1Visible(boolean flag){
      this.button1.Visible = flag;
}
```

You cannot access the button directly from Form1. (Actually you can,but it is not right way to solve it.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 f2 = new Form2();
        f2.Show();
        f2.setButton1Visible(true);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! How about set location?

Comment: Try the in same way to update the Location property http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tkzw7bw7.aspx

Comment: I still wouldnt mind to know the wrong way to solve this too.

Answer (score 1):

I think button1 is declared as private. Your code will work if you declare button1 as public.

```
public System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Imagine you control is in form 1. Set corresponding control "modifiers = public" from control property window

### Form 1

```
    private void ShowForm2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 NewForm = new Form2();
        NewForm.Owner = this;
        NewForm.Show();
    }
```

### In Form 2

```
    private void ChangeProperty_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       (this.Owner as Form1).MyButton.Visible = false;
    }

    //while doing this Control In Form1 will be hidden :)
```